# Lookup a value between values in 'From' and 'To' fields and update a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have two tables. One holds a series of ranges (tbRange)eg

```
ID  From   To     Score  
1   0.00   17.00  A  
2   17.00  22.50  B  
3   22.50  24.50  C+  
4   24.50  26.50  C  
5   26.50  31.50  C-  
6   31.50  44.00  D
```

the other table has a total value (tbValues) and an empty 'Score' field

```
BuildingID Totals Score
3065       22.10  NULL
3066       22.00  NULL
3067       23.86  NULL
```

I've been trying to query tbRange with an update query to ascertain and populate the tbValues.Score with the tbRange.Score where my tbValues.Totals lies between tbRange.From and tbRange.To but I can't get anywhere.

In the example 3 records above the desired outcome would be 'B', 'B', 'C+'

Thanks in advance

Comment: Simply JOIN the tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Using like this and let me know if it helps ?

```
  update aa
    set aa.Score = a.Score
    from tbRange as a 
    inner join tbValues as aa
    on aa.Totals BETWEEN a.[From] AND a.[To]
```

**EDITS**

I didn't noticed that there is two 24.0 so which grade will be implemented first ? 
So basically the soluction to this is we can set if Total is >= a.from AND Total is < a.to so thats how it will look for a better value But its upto you if you want it or not.

```
 update aa
    set aa.Score = a.Score
    from tbRange as a 
    inner join tbValues as aa
    on aa.Totals >= a.[From] AND aa.Totals < a.[To]
```

**IF IT WORKS THEN HOW IT WORK ??**

In sql we have a BETWEEN operator that can be used to specific select between Ranges .

Comment: Careful with border values, like `17.00`. Between is inclusive on both ends.

Comment: if a rows Range is below The total it will simply skip that . Correct me if i am wrong, and give me ref too .

Comment: If `aa.Totals` is `24.50`, which score gets to be updated? It's not deterministic. You can solve it by changing the `BETWEEN` for a `>=`and `<`, with the equal part depending on the OP's criteria.

Comment: Yes now i am getting it, little confused but got the most part .

Comment: This worked great thanks. The problem with the same values in From and To was actually an error on my part as I had limited the decimal places. I've increased them to 4 places now to show 24.5001 in the From column and 24.5000 in the To column.

Comment: Yeah that was smart move tho . But there are still possiblities that it will get repeated . A minor but still .